# Using eloquent in laravel to join third table. Best way to accomplish?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am trying to join all videos for a given track along with joining the make and model from the vehicles table.  Each video contains only one Vehicle from the vehicles table.  I am having difficulties using Eloquent syntax on how I can make this happen.

The Track model i built to grab all the videos is very straight forward and works well as written below:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Track extends Model
{

    public function video()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Video');
    }

}
```

I've written by Vehicles model as below:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Video extends Model
{
    function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Vehicle');
    }
}
```

The three database models look like the following

**tracks**

- id
- name
- city
- state
- url_key

**videos**

- id
- youtube_id
- date
- best_lap_time
- vehicles_id

**vehicles**

- id
- make
- model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below answer assumes your video() relation works well (as you said). But looking at your database schema and models, you don't have a column named track_id in your videos table, so I'm not sure about that.

Your vehicle relationship should look like this (you defined the inverse):

```
function vehicle()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Vehicle', 'vehicles_id');
}
```

Then your query should look something like this:

```
$result = \App\Track::with('video.vehicle')->get()
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to be what i'm looking for.  I do have a track_id in the videos table i just didn't list out all the columns (my fault).  Using that query it appears like its looking for a video_id on the vehicles table which there is not.

Comment: Can you confirm that your video() is definitely working? As in, it returns all videos connected to track when called $track->videos (maybe edit your tables structure, so others dont get confused).

Comment: And you said you tried putting the vehicle() relationship that I've posted (belongsTo with 2nd argument 'vehicles_id' - the column you have as foreign key) into the Video model? I'm not sure why this wouldn't work. The 2nd argument of [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) is the name of the foreign key on the current model's table (which is vehicles_id in your case).

Comment: You were exactly right devk.  I made some other ID10T mistake that was preventing this from working originaly.  Thank you